# Checkbox on table or dataframe

Tags: r, checkbox, checkboxlist, shiny

How do you select rows of data from a dataframe or table using checkboxes?
I've done the following code but it seems the checkbox items are columns and does not really display the results.

Thanks for your help.

#### server.R

```
   shinyServer(function(input, output) {
       dataset<-reactive({
         data(cars)
         cars
       })

       output$choose_data <- renderUI({
         checkboxGroupInput("dtab", "Data Table", dataset()) 
    })

       dataset2<-reactive({
         input$dtab         
    })      

       output$data_table <- renderTable({
         data2()                    
       })
    })
```

#### ui.R

```
   shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
         headerPanel(""),

         sidebarPanel(
         uiOutput("choose_data"),
         br()
         ),

        mainPanel(
        wellPanel("Data", tableOutput("data_table")
    ))))
```

Comment: I have almost exactly the same question -- have you figured it out?  I'm rendering an R data.frame using renderTable, and I want to have a column of checkboxes (*in* the table) that, when clicked, changes the corresponding entry in the column of the R data.frame to either TRUE or FALSE, depending on whether the checkbox is currently checked.  Can't find any examples on how this might be accomplished.

Comment: not really. havent really figured it out yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can try package `ReporteRs`, there's a function `FlexTable` for creating html table (or word table), an example :

```
library("shiny")
library("ReporteRs")
mymtcars <- head(mtcars)

# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Table with checkboxes"),
  tableOutput(outputId = "table"),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "out")
)
# server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderFlexTable({
    # Create checkboxes
    mymtcars$Name <- paste0('<label><input type="checkbox" id="car', seq_along(rownames(mymtcars)), '"> <span>', rownames(mymtcars), '</span></label>')
    mymtcars <- mymtcars[c("Name", names(mtcars))] # Put col 'Name' in the first place
    ft <- vanilla.table(mymtcars) # convert to FlexTable objet
    ft[, "Name", to = "header"] <- parLeft() # left align checkboxes
    ft[, "Name"] <- parLeft() # left align header
    return(ft)
  })
  # the inputs created are in input$car1, input$car2, ...
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    # results
    res <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(mymtcars), function(i) input[[paste0("car", i)]]))
    print(res)
    if (any(res)) {
      print(rownames(mymtcars)[res])
    }
  })
}
# launch app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The result looks like :

[image: ft_example]

For more informations about FlexTable objects you can look [here](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/FlexTable.html).

Answer (score 0):

An example. Notice how I set the labels, and use the id specified for the `checkboxGroupInput`, `choose_row`, as an input parameter for `output$data_table`. This can replace your `server.R` file.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data(cars)
  cars <- cars[1:10,] ## limit ourselves to first 10 rows for example

  ## a UI element that we can use for selecting rows
  output$choose_data <- renderUI({
    labels <- setNames( as.list(1:nrow(cars)), paste("Row", 1:nrow(cars)) )
    checkboxGroupInput("choose_row", "Select Rows", labels)
  })

  ## render the data.frame at the selected rows
  output$data_table <- renderTable({
    cars[input$choose_row, ]
  })
})
```

Comment: you missed the point. I want to display all the data as a table on the sidepanel with a checkbox for each row (not the name Row). The rows selected are displayed as a table on the mainPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Add some HTML tags and use `DT::datatable(escape = F) to display.
The following code is pretty easy to interpret.

1. `<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="styled">` is a checkbox tag.
2. `DT::datatable(escape = F)` builds a html page.

`{r}
library(tidyverse)
tibble(
    x = '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="styled">This is a checkbox'
) %>% 
    DT::datatable(escape = F)`

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have it checked by default?

Comment: @fifthace Absolutely, just change the syntax to `checked`, here is the reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox